# Passing global scope var to included file

Tags: php, scope

I'm trying to get a global var to show up in an included file. I'll replicate the path here:

```
$var = array();

funcA 
{
    global $var;
    $var = array('some'=>'values');

    funcB
    {
        global $var;

        //$var prints('some'=>'values')
        include_once('myfile.php');
    }
}
```

OR

```
funcA 
{
    $var = array('some'=>'values');

    funcB($var)
    {
        //$var prints('some'=>'values')
        include_once('myfile.php');
    }
}
myfile.php:
//prints own content (is included)
//$var is empty, whether declared global or not.
```

Am I missing a step?

**EDIT:** Before the upvote train of 'not using global variables' leaves me without an actual answer, the above still does not work even when `$var` is passed as a parameter from `funcA` to `funcB`. I have edited the code to demonstrate.

The file is included via file path, not url, but does reside in another directory - is that relevant?

**EDIT:** Even when initialising a variable *just before* including the file, the value is not passed to that file. The issue seems to be in the include method itself. I'm using `include_once()` and providing the full absolute path to the file.

Comment: whats your problem and why nested funcs :?

Comment: Please avoid using **global** variables.

Comment: The `var` variable does not transfer to the included file. The functions are not *actually* nested, that's just how they are called (funcB is called from within funcA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass as a parameter and/or use return values?  Your application shouldn't need to reply on globals, and is usually a sign of a design flaw.

```
function getVar() {
    return array('some'=>'values');
}

function printVar($var) {
    include_once('myfile.php');
    // print_r($var);
}

$var = getVar();
printVar($var);
```

If your problem is larger  than the example shows, you should take a look at [PHP's OOP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and start using classes/objects.  Check out some frameworks to help you dive right in too.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I've edited my question to show that the failure persists even when the variable is passed as a parameter, and even when simply declared with some dummy value immediately before the `include` call.

Comment: @Eamonn can you update your original question with `myfile.php` contents?  Or include a `test.php` file with the contents `<?php var_dump($var); ?>`.  According to the documentation, `include()` should inherit the variable scope of the line in which it was included (so it would have the variable scope of `printVar()`, which includes `$var`).

Comment: It appears to be some tricky scope issue - some functions declared before the include work, but constants defined at the root level do not. I think I will need to go back along the path and find where things go awry. Why something declared immediately beforehand would not show up, however, is a new one on me...

Comment: According to [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope." Sounds like my simplified example should work, not sure if there is something complicated going on with your variable scope elsewhere

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out.